# Parsing a HTML String without Element ID's

Tags: jquery, html, parsing, class

This may be a very simple question, but I haven't found an answer to this question that works in my situation yet. I am extremely new to jQuery and JavaScript, mind you. Anyway, I'm using a jQuery plug-in called "jGFeed" that returns to me an object containing important information about a feed. The code for such looks like this:

```
$.jGFeed('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=USOR0186&u=f', function(feed) {
    if(!feed) {
        return false;
    }
    var html = feed.entries[0].content;
}
```

By this point, the "html" variable will now contain a string of HTML code resembling something like this:

```
<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/28.gif"/><br />
<b>Current Conditions:</b><br />
Mostly Cloudy, 73 F<BR /><BR />
<b>Forecast:</b><BR />
Tue - Showers Late. High: 74 Low: 50<br />
Wed - Scattered Thunderstorms. High: 70 Low: 42<br /><br />
<a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Klamath_Falls__OR/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USOR0186_f.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/>
(provided by <a href="http://www.weather.com" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>
```

Now I've seen a lot of ways to parse HTML strings to get the content I want, but they all refer to an element's class or ID in order to find the desired information. What I really want is the image url (http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/28.gif), the current weather text and temperature (Mostly Cloudy, 73 F), and the two days provided along with their temperatures and conditions. Is there a way to extract just this information with jQuery?

Comment: do you have any kind of live example where I could see the exact formatting of the returned value?

Comment: Not at the moment, no. The second code block contains the exact return value (or an example of since this is merely the current entry of an RSS feed) that I'm trying to parse through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery selectors to search within your variable by doing like this:

```
$(selector,yourVariableWhichHasThatHTML)
```

So you want to get the image url?

```
$('img',yourVariableWhichHasThatHTML).attr('src');
```

But I would guess that in your jGfeed plugin you could straightly access to these via the feed variable? if you are using firebug or chrome, try writing: console.log(feed); after var html = feed.entries[0].content. Then if you open developer tools and console tab, you should see what the feed variable has eaten.

Comment: I didn't even think about accessing the attribute... Yeah, that helps a bit, thanks.